# php autocomplete with vim

Tags: php, vim, autocomplete

i'm looking for an php autocomplete solution for vim. I already was at this thread:
[Vim PHP omni completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224838/vim-php-omni-completion/2316468)
but it doesn't work for me.
I generate the tags file with this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec ctags -V -f tags \
-h \".php\" -R \
--exclude=\"\.git\" \
--totals=yes \
--language-force=PHP \
--tag-relative=yes \
--PHP-kinds=+cfiv \
--regex-PHP='/(abstract)?\s+class\s+([^ ]+)/\2/c/' \
--regex-PHP='/(static|abstract|public|protected|private)\s+(final\s+)?function\s+(\&\s+)?([^ (]+)/\4/f/' \
--regex-PHP='/interface\s+([^ ]+)/\1/i/' \
--regex-PHP='/\$([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/\1/v/' \
kernel/classes/
```

but the autocomplete is not as desired. I don't even know if the plugin is loading.
so, how can i see if the plugin is loading? (the plugin is located under bundle, i use pathogen, and other plugins do work..)
it is necessary to activate something else?
i have VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3, Exuberant Ctags 5.8

thanks

Answer (score 4):

I´ve also tried to get php autocompletion working better in vim. I used the phpcomplete.vim plugin, but found out that there was a bug when using more than one tag file (what is not unusual in most vimrc configs).
In this case it just searches the first tagfile to resolve the class-filename, and then fallbacks to the standard completion (showing a long long not scope aware list)

However, i´ve forked the plugin and fixed the bug. For me it´s working wonderful now:
https://github.com/sebastiankessler/phpcomplete.vim

Answer (score 3):

If your projects is a composer project then checkout my [phpcomplete-extended](https://github.com/m2mdas/phpcomplete-extended#phpcomplete-extended) plugin. For Symfony2 land Laravel projects also checkout [phpcomplete-extended-symfony](https://github.com/m2mdas/phpcomplete-extended-symfony#phpcomplete-extended-symfony) and [phpcomplete-extended-laravel](https://github.com/m2mdas/phpcomplete-extended-laravel#phpcomplete-extended-laravel) plugins respectively.

Answer (score 2):

[Padawan](https://github.com/padawan-php/padawan.php) with [Deoplete](https://github.com/Shougo/deoplete.nvim) are great solutions for having a robust PHP autocompletion in Neovim. For Vim you can use [Neocomplete](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim) instead of Deoplete.

I wrote an article how to make a [Vim PHP IDE](https://thevaluable.dev/vim-php-ide/) if somebody is interested :)

Comment: Neocomplete is not maintained anymore but Deoplete is Vim8 compatible

Answer (score 1):

What would be the desired effect? What do you expect? What do you get? Vim has no "autocomplete" feature: its own brand of completion is called "omni completion" and is not automatic at all.

I've been using the phpComplete script linked in one of the other question's answers in conjunction with `ctags` without problems for quite some time. In fact I wrote the following examples thinking I was using it but I forgot I've removed a bunch of scripts and plugins some weeks ago, including `phpComplete.vim`.

So the following works very nicely with stock Vim 7.3/Exuberant Ctags 5.8.

With **`a.php`**:

```
<?php
  class MyClass {
    public function MyClass(argument) {
      echo 'Hello.';
    }
    private function secret() {
      echo 'Shhhh…';
    }
    public function say() {
      echo 'what?';
    }
  }
?>
```

and the cursor as indicated in **`b.php`**

```
<?php
  include 'a.php';

  $example = new MyClass();
  $example->| //cursor here
?>
```

`<C-x><C-o>` gives me these choices:

```
say( f
MyClass( f
```

I don't get a mile-long list of builtin functions and I don't even get private methods.

Comment: jep, this behavior would be desire. using your code as test (plus some static vars), when i press <C-x><C-o> at $example->| i get a long list of functions, like ArrayIterator::rewind or PDO::exec and so on. and if i press at $example::| i do get the public functions. one more thing, how did you generate your tags?

Comment: I use a simple `:!ctags -R .` to generate my `tags` file after each `:w`. Like I said, I don't have any PHP-related plugins/settings anymore: I use Vim's default omni completion in two slightly different Vim 7.3 builds on Mac OS X and Ubuntu 10.10 in conjunction with the same Exuberant Ctags 5.8 as you and have the same behaviour on the two setups. It works just as well in the Vim 7.2 I have on a sandbox VPS of mine. Make sure you have (re-)generated your `tags` file before doing `<C-x><C-o>`.

Comment: vim does have autocomplete feature - Ctrl + N works pretty well for bash & perl

Comment: and the youcompleteme plugin automates the ctrl+n